# How to implement a session timer inside web.config in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

This article shows how to implement [sesstionState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28vs.80%29.aspx) inside web.config file. But what I want to do is to clear the session when user is idle for 15 minutes or higher. And reset the time when the user is active within the scope of time. Is this possible? If not how could I do this without using any javascript code/jQuery?

BTW, I have my BaseController where all Controllers inherits to it.  Hope someone could give me the better idea.

Comment: It's TimeOut in the link you provided.

Comment: I'm thinking that if the time elapsed, it will clear the session. That is what I need, plus resetting the time when user is active. May be I misunderstood the usage, please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the timeout property in the `<sessionState>` configuration section.

```
<sessionState
    ...

    timeout="number of minutes"

    ...
</sessionState>
```

Documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx